# Powershell remoting from Windows 2012 to Windows 2003 (Exchange)

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, powershell-2.0

I´m trying to execute get-mailbox cmd-let from Windows 2012 powershell to Windows 2003.
Windows 2003 have a exchange server 2007 and act as hub role.
The code is:

```
invoke-command -ComputerName exchangeXXX -ScriptBlock {
Add-PSSnapIn Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin
Add-PSSnapIn Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.Support
Get-ChildItem C:\
get-mailbox

}
```

The get-childitem c:\ and Add-PSsnapIn commands work, but get-mailbox doesn´t work it returns an error:

```
Processing data for a remote command failed with the following error message: El proceso host del proveedor WSMan no devolvió una respuesta 
correcta.  Puede que un proveedor del proceso host haya tenido un comportamiento incorrecto. For more information, see the 
about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (exchangeXX:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : JobFailure
    + PSComputerName        : exchangeXX
```

Any idea about what is happening ? Any other idea to create/list a users via powershell remoting? I need snapins in local computer?

Thanks.

Comment: afaik you can use exchange cmdlets only from Exchange 2007 and above.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your Exchange deployment? Number of servers, Exchange versions and so on.

Comment: Is an exchange 2007, there are two servers , one edge and one hub.
Is with lastest updates.